# Dehydration of carboxylic acids with phosphoric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-reduction

[image: Question & Options]

To find **Z** one must find **X**. Finding **Y** is of no use to find **Z**.

I get **X** as:

[image: Product X]

After addition of $\ce{H2/Pd-C}$, the unsaturated portion becomes saturated and the carboxylic acid remains unchanged.

However I am unsure what does $\ce{H3PO4}$ do to this (new) carboxylic acid? I was unable to find any information. I did find information regarding dehydration with $\ce{P2O5}$, but unsure what to make use out of it.

After looking at (unofficial/3rd party) solutions, I saw that $\ce{H3PO4}$ protonates the $\ce{-OH}$ part of the carboxylic acid (since it is a much stronger acid than the organic acid?) then $\ce{H2O}$ leaves, rendering a carbo-cation at the carbonyl carbon, followed by EAS at the ring.

However, I do not see how $\ce{H3PO4}$ exactly works with the carboxylic acid. I have merely guessed that the $\ce{-OH}$ portion gets protonated (since, this was the only thing I predicted would happen). I really do not know why this happens and how it happens.

Hints and reference material or examples would be appreciated.

The original question is taken from the JEE (Advanced) [2018] Paper-1.

Comment: Friedel-Crafts acylation...

Comment: Sure I do know that happens, however for that to happen, a carbonyl cation has to form. I do not know how exactly the carbonyl cation forms here by H3PO4. @orthocresol

Comment: Ok, but you already (correctly) described what happens. What else do you really want?

Comment: @orrthocresol Please see that I said the sources are third party and unofficial. I would like to know H3PO4 exactly causes dehydration of the carboxylic acid - because I have never seen this before. I will reframe my question to make it more clearer.

Comment: phosphoric acid, usually in the form of polyphosphoric acid, is a powerful dehydrating agent. It can be regarded as the anhydride of phosphoric acid capturing OH by formation of an HO-P bond. A brief review is here: http://reag.paperplane.io/00002328.htm   Its major advantage over sulfuric acid for cyclisations is that it is not an oxidising agent.

Comment: @Waylander Could you please kindly elaborate on what may have happened had sulfuric acid been used? (As in what type of oxidation might have occured?)

Comment: Sulfonation of the benzene ring   https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/arenes/other.html  also oxidation to phenols and hydroquinones

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $\ce{-OH}$ part will not get protonated, since its lone pair is in resonance with the carbonyl part of the $\ce{-COOH}$ group. Instead, the lone pair of the carbonyl part will give its lone pair to $\ce{H+}$.

Something like this :-

[image: Mechanism]

It may look insignificant because the product is same, but this is the correct mechanism.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! You might want to get acquainted with [MathJax/mhchem formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/69977) and [drawing chemical structures](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/how-do-i-draw-chemical-compounds-and-chemical-reaction-mechanisms-and-add-it-to/3737#3737), it helps make posts look more presentable. Have a great day. -[From Review](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/99976)

Comment: And what is the reason why H3PO4 does this? Its dehydration properties or its much stronger acidity or both? What about acids such as H2SO4?